# Why the difference between "size" and "size on disk" is larger than the size of the cluster?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, memory, filesystems, ntfs

On Windows10, The "size" of **only one** file is 20325700 Bytes, but the "size on disk" of that file is 20578304 Bytes. The size of cluster is 128 KB. So, 20578304 - 20325700 = 246.7KB > 128KB. Why the difference between "size" and "size on disk" is larger than the size of the cluster? I think it should be less than the size of cluster.

Comment: For example, the file contains additional streams...

Comment: @Akina Thanks. Is the additional stream not included in the size of the file?

Comment: No, only main file stream size is shown as file size. Whereas on-disk size includes all clusters occupied by all file streams.

Comment: Test. Create tiny text file (~ 2 kbytes). Then copy huge (1-2 Mbytes or more) text file into its stream (CMD command like `type hugetext.txt > tinytext.txt:additional.stream`) and investigate the result.

Comment: @Akina I do your test, and it is like what you said. Thank you.

Comment: Of course this is not the only possible reason... but it is the most obvious for me.

Comment: @Akina Is there anyway that I can check whether my file has additional streams or not?

Comment: [Windows SysInternals > Streams](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/streams)

Comment: @Akina OK. Thank you.

Comment: @Akina Hello. I check my file using Streams, my file does have an additional stream, the size of the stream is 909.  20325700 + 909 = 20326609.  20578304 - 20326609 = 245.8KB.  It is still larger than the size of cluster. But, when I delete the additional stream,  the "size on disk" is 20328448.  20578304 - 20328448 = 249856 > 909. So when I delete the additional stream, I delete so much more than 909. So, the size of the stream is not accurate?

Comment: ROUNDUP( 20325700 bytes / 128 kbytes/cluster ) = ROUNDUP (155,0727844 ) = 156 clusters, 909 bytes = 1 cluster, totally 157 clusters * 128 kbytes/cluster = 20578304 bytes.

Comment: @Akina I see. The additional stream doesn't share the cluster with the file. Thank you so so much.